# How to show Hijri Calendar in DatepickerDialog view in Android using jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, hijri

I want to display Hijri dates in DatePickerDialog in jetpack compose without using any 3rd party libraries.

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance() //this opens up gregorian calendar I need to show Hijri dates
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show native Islamic(hijri) Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380118/how-to-show-native-islamichijri-calendar)

Comment: No.. this they are only converting to Hijri but I want to show the dates in datepicker in Hijri format.